# Extendible claws and augmented vision - Looking for a book?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I seem to recall a pair of books about someone who had had extensive genetic engineering, where he could make his nails grow into claws.  I also remember something about touching his incisor teeth to change his vision to night vision?

And something about an emerald ring that he picked up which couldn't then be removed?

I think it was 2 books... and I think he was a pilot or something....

Does anyone remember it? It would have been from the early 80's I guess?

The two books I had didn't finish the story, as I recall...  Was the trilogy ever finished?

Comment: Are you sure it was 'genetic engineering' and not magic?  Because those could also be enchantments.  Any other details you recall?  Character names, scenes that stood out?

Comment: Extendable claws and amped vision are fairly common body mods in SF. I can think of three off the top of my head (Pohl's Man-Plus, one of the assassins in Zelazny's Roadmarks, and of course Molly/Sally from Gibson's Sprawl trilogy). Can you think of any more details? Even the book cover might help.

Comment: Haven't read much Pohl, and Zelazny and I have an off/on relationship (Early Amber books were amazing, for example! :D ) but I think I'm going to have to look up those suggestions, because it's a genre I miss and really loved!

Answer (score 5):

I had a flash of inspiration last night, after writing this post!  It was *[The Space Mavericks](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1741196.The_Space_Mavericks)* and *[Children of the Night](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1741210.Children_of_the_Night)*, by Michael Kring.

[image: Book Cover for The Space Mavericks]

> First in an early 1980s space opera series which was never completed. Trading ships are divided into those belonging to the big conglomerates, and independents known as mavericks, with no love lost between the two groups. Enough mavericks have been beaten or even killed that maverick pilot Fripp Enos has had himself modified -- an alien medical procedure that enhances the body's natural defences in some startling ways. Few people had the procedure done even before it was outlawed, so Fripp can usually win a fight against even an armed opponent. Which is useful, because even though Fripp doesn't look for trouble, trouble inevitably finds him.

Looks like there's [a call to try and find out how the story finished](http://fantasy-faction.com/forum/fantasy-book-discussion/where-is-michael-kring/).

Comment: When you return, you can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark, and we highly encourage you to do so.